# to find the value of angle A in the given equation

Tags: trigonometry

```
4 sin A cos A = 1 - 2 sin A + 2 cos A
```

I could not find the value of either sin A or cos A in the above equation. So please direct me on how to find the values of 'A'

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We have $\underbrace{1-2\sin A}+2\cos A(\underbrace{1-2\sin A})=0$

$\sin A=\sin B\implies x=n\pi+(-1)^nB$ where $n$ is any integer

and $\cos A=\cos C\implies A=2m\pi\pm C$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: the process is helpful but the four angles I got as a solution are 30,60,150,300 degrees. But the answers given are 30,120,150,240 degrees. So what to do?

Comment: @TheViper, $$2\cos A+1=0\iff\cos A=-\dfrac12=\cos ?$$

Comment: Sorry! Got it. thank you

Comment: If you got it then feel free to mark it as accepted answer and move on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$
4\cos \theta \sin \theta  = (2\sin \theta - 1) (2\cos \theta +1) -2\sin\theta +2\cos \theta + 1= ?
$$